# Inserting a huge amount of data in sqlite database taking a long time

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

Im inserting a huge amount of data into my sqlite database. Now it takes a long time  to complete the process which would be frustuating for the user. Could anyone here give me any idea on how to make this process fast or any alternative.

Plss help me..

Comment: Does it matter if the transaction finishes before the program moves on?

Comment: try lasy loading technique .. even with these if you are using much of  DB this is obvious .. you can user NSUser Defaults few times instead

Answer (score 1):

1. If you're storing images or things like that, consider not storing that in the database, as it's pretty inefficient to do so. Store that sort of binary data in the Documents folder and if you need to keep track of it in the database, do so by storing the filenames in the database, but not the image.
2. If at all possible, do these operations in the background, such as through [Grand Central Dispatch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) or [`NSOperationQueue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). These technologies are also discussed in the [Concurrency Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091). If you're doing this with a SQLite wrapper, such as the excellent [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (which I heartily recommend you investigate if you haven't already), you can use its `FMDatabaseQueue` (which uses GCD) to coordinate background database operations with foreground database queries. Because it's using queues, you'll just want to make sure to break the background database operations in smaller tasks if possible to avoid the perception of blocking foreground database operations.

Answer (score 0):

`NSOperationQueue` provide the threads used to run their operations.

Create `NSInvocationOperation` objects and add it in the array of `NSOperationQueue`.

```
 NSInvocationOperation *insertOperationObject1 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(insertMethod1) object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *insertOperationObject2 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(insertMethod2) object:nil];
    NSInvocationOperation *insertOperationObject3 = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(insertMethod3) object:nil];
```

//adding database fetch operations to an NSOperationQueue

```
 NSOperationQueue     *m_opqInsertQueue = [[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init] autorelease];
        [m_opqCustomerProfileDataFetchQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:1];
        [m_opqCustomerProfileDataFetchQueue addOperations:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:insertOperationObject1, insertOperationObject2, insertOperationObject3,  nil] waitUntilFinished:NO];
```